# Checking for html elements in CefSharp

Tags: html, vb.net, cefsharp

Hello I'm looking to check for an element within an html document within a CefSharp browser. CefSharp is an embeded, full-featured standards-complaint web browser for C# / .NET website [here](http://cefsharp.github.io/)

Previously, You where able to check for html element ID's via this method:

```
If (Form2.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("getnamehistory_arrow") IsNot Nothing) Then

End if
```

I have gone through some of the [Frequently asked questions](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJSWithResult) sections of the GitHub but cannot find anything that relates. If anyone here if familiar with CefSharp please feel free to give suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It is in c# but it works..

```
        string script = string.Format("$('getnamehistory_arrow').length;");
        browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var response = x.Result;

            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
            {
                var resultres = Convert.ToString(response.Result);
                if (resultres == "1")
                {
                    //have 
                }
                else
                {
                    //don't have
                }
            }
        });
```